# "btrfs filesystem show" gives me "failed to read" errors

Tags: btrfs

My /home is a raid1 btrfs partition spanning two disk. As far as I can tell, it's working fine.

This morning I wanted to check the status of the partition so I entered the `btrfs filesystem show` command and I only got errors :

```
$ btrfs filesystem show /dev/sdd1
failed to read /dev/sdb
failed to read /dev/sdb1
failed to read /dev/sdc
failed to read /dev/sdc1
failed to read /dev/sdd
failed to read /dev/sdd1
Btrfs v0.20-rc1
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I answered my own questions while I was typing it on askubuntu.com. Since I previously did not find the somewhat obvious answer on the Internet I though I would add my question anyway and answer it myself. For posterity.

The command need to be run as su:

```
sudo btrfs filesystem show
```